# How can I exclude child's child from the result?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am integrating Sequelize to the express project with MySQL DB.
I have a problem when calling the find method of the model.
The result contains all nested children. But I like to remove the child's child from the result.
This is the code that I tried to do but failed.

```
return await db.tutorial.findAll({
      include: [{ model: Tag, as: 'tag', nested: false}]
    })
```

Here is the screenshot of the result. 
[image] 
How can I set an include filter option to exclude the child's child info from the result?

I can share more detailed information if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution with myself.
I solved this problem by editing the include statement as like below:

```
return await db.tutorial.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Tag,
        as: 'tag',
        through:{
          attributes: []
        }
      }]
    })
```

Thank you for your attention. :)